# Is it normal to hear only a tone when listening to a VOR?

Tags: vor

I was using my RTL-SDR to listen to the VORTAC at [Del Norte County Airport / Jack McNamara Field (KCEC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_Norte_County_Airport) on 109 MHz. All I heard was a constant unmodulated carrier. Is that normal?

Comment: Were you listening in AM mode?

Comment: @tedder42 upper sideband set to 108.999 MHz, so the carrier was at 1 kHz in the audio output. Should I have been using AM?

Comment: definitely try AM. Airband is AM. I don't have a SDR set up to test though.